# Users stay authenticated (big session timeout) if I delete user from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `User` table. I'm using `Forms` authentication and have the following code for logon:

```
 public JsonResult LogOn(FormCollection form)
 {
        var agent = SiteUserRepository.CheckAgent(form["Email"], form["Password"]);
        if (agent == null)
            return Json(new
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                Message = "Wrong email or password"
            });
        SiteUserRepository.UpdateLastLogon(agent.Email);

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(agent.Email, true);
        ApplicationSession.CurrentUser = agent;

        return Json(new
            {
                IsSuccess = true
            });

 }
```

The `ApplicationSession` is my wrapper for `Session` object.

```
public static class ApplicationSession
{
    private const string _currentUser = "CurrentUser";
    public static SiteUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Session[_currentUser];
            if (user != null)
                return (SiteUser)user;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[_currentUser] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

The session timeout equals 1440 (24 h). I need exactly this value.
For example user login on site. Then I delete this user from DB. And user will be authenticated (if they don't click Log Off, of course). What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a cookie.  Your code needs to check for the cookie and if it doesn't exist, or the time has expired on it, you create a new one.

I think this will show you a nice example:

[C# Cookies based on login information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726896/c-sharp-cookies-based-on-login-information)

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookies-ASP.NET.aspx

a remember me checkbox type implementation with an expiration of a day could be done something like this:

```
if (chBox.Checked)

      {
          HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie_Remember"); //new cookie object

          Response.Cookies.Remove("Cookie_Remember"); //This will remove previous cookie
          Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie_Remember); //This will create new cookie

          Cookie_Remember.Values.Add("UserInfo", txt_username.Text); //Add User Name 

        // You can add multiple values

          DateTime CookieExpir= DateTime.Now.AddDays(5); //Cookie life

          Response.Cookies["Cookie_Remember"].Expires = CookieExpir; //Maximum day of cookie's life       
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to only allow users to be deleted from your repository/database via your application.

When a user is deleted, force log them out:

```
//Delete the user
SiteUserRepository.DeleteUser(agent);

//Log them out
FormsAuthentication.Signout();
```

Comment: I don't think that it will work. Because, I delete user from other applciation (CMS).